# What is the purpose and history behind Centralizers, Normalizers, Stabilizers in abstract algebra?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, math-history, motivation

I believe that these concepts are a means of determining how a group acts on a set, but I am not sure what valuable information this might reveal about the group. Related to this, who invented these concepts and why? The motivation aspect is lacking from nearly every math textbook I study, including Dummit Foote. So I'm left wondering why I'm learning what I'm learning.

Comment: They are a measure of how commutative and normal a subgroup is. It is similar to how the kernel of a homomorphism measures how injective it is and cokernel measures how surjective the function is.